# how to collect a metric kafka_log_log_size?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-exporter

metric kafka_log_log_size in grafana(datasource victoria metrics)
I assembled metrics by kafka exporter(https://github.com/danielqsj/kafka_exporter)  but metric kafka_log_log_size not going to.

how to build such a metric?

Comment: What do you mean by "build"? Either the exporter has it, or it doesn't... Look at the readme for the documented values, where log size does not exist https://github.com/danielqsj/kafka_exporter#metrics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kafka.log:name=Size` is a JMX metric.

You need to use JMX exporter to get it, not "Kafka exporter"